# I have forgotten my ID proof and I'm doing an Indian domestic flight. Can I still fly?

Tags: legal, india, paperwork, domestic-travel

I am travelling from Delhi to Indore, a domestic flight. I forgot to take ID proof. Can I still fly?

Comment: Do you have any id? Driver's license? Student ID? Anything else? How long before your flight? Is your flight flexible? (i.e. can you change the flight?)

Comment: no.....i have flight tomorrow morning.

Comment: i have e adhaar flile in my laptop

Comment: will xerox of passport works?

Comment: A copy of an ID isn't an ID.

Comment: @Karlson: ...unless that copy is an Indian Aadhaar card. e-Aadhaar copies are secure electronic documents and considered valid proofs of identity across India. See my answer below for details.

Comment: @pankajafle: I know I'm ridiculously late to help with your particular situation, but note for the future: e-Aadhaar copy should work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 13):

As per the guidelines, it is mandatory to carry a **Government issued photo identification (ID) proof** along with the E-Ticket for domestic flights in India. The same is verified by the airport security as well as the airline at the check in counter. The valid photo identification documents allowed are: **[Valid Passport](https://web.archive.org/web/20160120103859/http://www.solobackpacker.com/2012/11/03/points-to-remember-while-travelling-on-domestic-flights-within-india/) / Driving License / Election Voter Card / Ration Card/ Aadhar Card/ PAN Card/ Photo Identity cards issued by Government** On presenting your photo ID proof and E-Ticket copy, your boarding pass will be issued. You need to present the original copy of the ID proof.

Also, as per Air India Support, a photocopy of the ID will not work. Because at the airport they accept only the original proof of identity, they will not accept any photocopy of the proof of identity. To avoid any inconvenience at the airport, please ask your friend to carry an affidavit which will be accepted. In addition to this, you can carry an Affidavit from a Notary Public (preferably with your photo over the Affidavit) stating your name and address etc. which will work as your identity document.

[image: Air India live chat help. Transcription below.]

> **User**: Can he still travel with the valid photocopy of the ID proof?
> **User**: he has photo copy of passport and soft copy of his Adhaar card
> **Air India Support**: I'd like to inform you at airport they accept only original identity proof they will not accept any photo copy of your Identity proof so avoid any inconvenience at airport please ask your friend to carry an affadavit which will be accepted.
> **User**: ok
> **User**: Affadavit from Notary public?
> **Air India Support**: Yes it is correct.
> **User**: and do I need to have photo also over Affadavit?
> **Air India Support**: I am sorry for it that information will be provided by them only but in general information it will be require then only it will be acceptable as Identity for any specific person.

This Affidavit you can easily get from Notary officials sitting near the court area, or any office which you know and you can tell them that you need it for this purpose. You may need to show them your Passport copy and Adhaar card copy (preferably color printed) to prove your identity. They may charge you some fee for this document.

**On the top of all**, if you have 1-2 days for your travel then you must get your documents courier to you by 1-day shipping facility like **FedEx, DTDC or FirstFlight** etc. This will solve all your issues and you don't have to waste your time at the airport for such things.

**Note:** Photo Credit Card are also not accepted as Identity proof (this was mentioned on one of the sites that you can use that, but as per Air India support it is not accepted as ID proof).

Comment: This is not true in case of Aadhaar. There _is_ no "original" of an Aadhaar card, all copies are equally "original" (legally). See my answer below.

Answer (score 11):

An e-Aadhaar copy is valid, legal proof of identity throughout India, just as good as the "original". In fact this is one of the primary benefits of the Aadhaar system.

I quote the UIDAI website in this regard:

> This [Aadhaar] number will serve as a proof of identity and address, anywhere in India. Aadhaar letter received via India Post and e-Aadhaar downloaded from UIDAI website are equally valid.

Here's the relevant page from the official Aadhaar website: https://uidai.gov.in/aapka-aadhaar.html

The e-Aadhaar website also lets citizens download the e-Aadhaar easily from the website with relevant details: https://eaadhaar.uidai.gov.in/

---

**UPDATE 30-05** - I confirmed with IndiGo customer support that e-Aadhaar copy can be used for entering the airport as well as boarding flights.

Comment: Can we make copy of e-Adhaar ? If that's case isn't it same as a photocopy of an original ID.

Comment: @AshishGaur because the e-Aadhaar is a digital document, any copy of it is identical. That is different from physical documents like PAN card, Voter ID, etc. for which there is only 1 valid "original" copy. In the case of e-Aadhaar, any digital copy is _legally_ just as good as the original physical one you got.

Comment: Ok, my doubt was if I take a pic or scan my Aadhar card, that won't be considered as a legal document, right ? There should be something different with e-Aadhar.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying that I strongly recommend that you carry an original government issued ID proof with you while travelling by air. There is a wide list of documents you can carry including:

1-Passport

2-PAN card

3-Adhar card

4-Drivers Licence

5-Voters Identity Card

6-Photo ID card issued by any of the following organizations/Institutions

```
Central Government or any of its Ministries.

Statutory / Regulatory authorities

State Govt. or any of its Ministries

Public Sector Undertaking (established under GOI or State Govt)

State Govt. of J&K

Bar council

Senior Citizen card issued by State/Central Govt.

Govt. of India to Persons of Indian Origin [PIO card]

Defence Dept / Ministry of defence for Defence personnel & their dependents

Public Financial institutions / Public sector banks
```

But if you really want to take a chance then I can also tell you that I've successfully entered airports on Credit and Debit Cards with a picture