# Domestic Flight ID in India

Tags: air-travel, india, paperwork, airport-security

I just want to know , if there is any procedure for senior citizen who has no ID proof to be shown at the Airport. It important for that senior citizen to travel for some medication to other state in India. 
As the ID proof applied for is delayed due to still some ongoing procedure and the tickets and medication are just booked.
Please can you help with if there is any legal procedure , which would allow the senior citizen to take her medication on time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have forgotten my ID proof and I'm doing an Indian domestic flight - can I still fly?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57142/i-have-forgotten-my-id-proof-and-im-doing-an-indian-domestic-flight-can-i-sti)

Comment: I cannot find the correct link, but if she has a photo-passbook of nationalised bank (with photo attested by bank official), then it may be accepted. Otherwise, if somebody else is also travelling on the same ticket, the airport security may allow her to enter airport based on accompanying passenger's ID (but it depends of the security guy)

Answer (score 2):

It would be very difficult for anybody to travel by air without ID proof, as how would you prove that the name on ticket, and person travelling is same person. But fortunately, in domestic air travel in India, there are plethora of photoID proofs you could use (any one of them). [Air India](http://www.airindia.in/documents-to-carry.html) says:

> For domestic travel within India, valid photo identification, namely, a passport, Income Tax PAN Card, Voter’s ID or Driving license is mandatory.

Also add Aadhar card to above list.

Note that any one of these is to prove that you are who you claim you are. If you are also claiming any fare discount, you might need something to back that up i.e. student card, army ID, age certificate etc.

If you do not have any of above in original, airport security might not even let you enter airport building. And evrn by rail travel, you need to provr yourself unless you are travelling in general unreserved class.

Nobody is stopping senior citizen from taking medication, can somebody else travel and bring the medicine?

Comment: Hey thanks  for your help, However it is not about just getting the medicine, it's about the treatment(Hospitalization). So has to be present physically.

Comment: @Prabesh.. ok, No Worries.. can you get a notarized letter with your photo, from a gazetted officer like school principal, police officer, bank manager or something. Or do you have a bank passbook with photo or like? These both might work in rail. But for air travel, there is very high chance that passenger needs one of the official photo ID. Try to ask airline helpdesk?