# Can I fly from Kolkata to Imphal without any documents?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, india, minors

I am 16 years old and I don't have any documents except my birth certificate and my students identity card is also expired. I am going to Kolkata to Imphal to apply for my adhar card. So how can I fly? Is there any way to fly?

Comment: Are you flying alone?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can’t fly without ID as per [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57142/i-have-forgotten-my-id-proof-and-im-doing-an-indian-domestic-flight-can-i-stil):

> As per the guidelines, it is mandatory to carry a Government issued photo identification (ID) proof along with the E-Ticket for domestic flights in India.

Valid ID are:

> The valid photo identification documents allowed are: Valid Passport / Driving License / Election Voter Card / Ration Card/ Aadhar Card/ PAN Card/ Photo Identity cards issued by Government On presenting your photo ID proof and E-Ticket copy, your boarding pass will be issued.

(Same Source)

Comment: OP being a minor may be exempted from these requirements if he is travelling with his parent/guardian.